# How to check if there is Data in a BufferedReader for 10 Seconds

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm currently using a `BufferedReader` in java and would like to know how I can keep checking if there is data in this reader for about 10 seconds and then to stop checking. How would this be achieved? I currently have this which just reads from the buffer once. How would I keep checking to see if `ServerInput` has data and then to react upon that data?

```
BufferedReader ServerInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocketConnection.getInputStream()));

while ((StringInput = ServerInput.readLine()) != null) 
{
   System.out.println(StringInput);
};
```

Comment: @codeMan A terrible idea, when socket read timeouts already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`BufferedReader#readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) blocks until receive a line of text. What you need is to set a timeout to the underlying socket via [`Socket#setSoTimeout(int timeout)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29).

Comment: Please can you explain a little bit more? I'm a bit of a newbie

Comment: @Roberto I am assuming that `ClientSocketConnection` is a socket, then just use `ClientSocketConnection.setSoTimeout(10000)`. After that, `ServerInput.readLine()` block until either you get a line of text or otherwise `SocketTimeoutException` will be thrown. Please consider changing the variable names in which each starts with small letter instead.